# RHEL how can I add a keyboard shortcut on minified version?

Tags: terminal, rhel, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal

I have a very small RHEL install, and there is no keyboard shortcut manager which would normally be located somewhere like "Applications -> Preferences -> Keyboard".

I have the dconf-editor -> xkb-options which wants a format similar to (but not correct):

```
['gnome-terminal', '<Ctrl>+<Alt>+t']
```

But I can't find anywhere that explains how to use the dconf-editor to create keyboard shortcuts.

To the best of my knowledge no other software exists on the computer to set keyboard shorts.  I know I have the `gconftool-2` utility, but every example I find has the path inside of the gconf-editor set to something inside of `/apps/` and I don't have anything inside of apps except `gconf-editor`

Any suggestions?